# What is a coordinate reference system in GIS? How is it different from a projection system?

Tags: gis

We hear a lot about CRS in GIS. I am working with QGIS and whenever I add a layer I need to specify the CRS but what I am confused about what exactly is a CRS and how is it different projection system. Why do countries have their own CRS and how is it determined?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ (please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for info about the scope of StackOverflow)

Comment: See this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/664/1249

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was very informative but I am still confused why countries have their own CRS. We use WGS84 for the web maps hence whole world uses the same datum or CRS. But when it comes to core GIS calculation every country has their own defined CRS and datum.

Comment: Datums vary in the [ellipsoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid) (i.e. models of the shape of the earth) they use. Some are fairly accurate across the entire globe, while others are more accurate for certain regions. Coordinate reference systems are based on a particular datum. There are unprojected (geographic) coordinate systems, with coordinates expressed in degrees, and projected coordinate systems ("projections"), with coordinates expressed in a planar unit like metres or feet.

Comment: Projection entails a sequence of transformations that represents the curved surface on a flat plane. There are many ways to do this, and each will suffer from some form of distortion (e.g. in distance, area, scale, and/or angles). Some are more fit-for-purpose than others, depending on what aspects need to be accurately reflected.

Comment: As I said, this is not the place for this type of question. You should (1) read  [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/664/1249) in addition to the other one I linked, and (2) if still unclear, ask the question over at [gis.se]. There are plenty of other good refs online if you do a bit of searching around phrases like "projection vs crs" or "datum vs crs". ArcGIS docs might also be useful, e.g. [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Projection_basics_the_GIS_professional_needs_to_know).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and answer. From next time I will ask these types of questions in http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, most APIs use the WGS84 format to specify geographical coordinates, which is briefly explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84) Wikipedia article. Basically, the coordiantes are [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) referring to an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) whose center is located at earth's center of gravity.

Comment: I am sorry for asking you to explain in detail. But are all coordinate reference system a specific kind of format in which the location on the earth surface is calculated. How to differentiate between these CRS?

Answer (score 0):

The earth is a sphere, and not a completely round one. However we would still like it as if it was flat to make proper maps and make measurements.
For example, using WGS84 on a map of Norway would make it look horribly distorted. 
that is why different regions have their own projections for their own cartographic needs.

I found a good definition of a CRS [here](http://www.crs-geo.eu/nn_124224/crseu/EN/CRS__Overview/definition-crs__node.html). For al intends and purposes it is the same as its projection.

Comment: Cannot open the link.